# Is there an established term to describe quarterly repeating transactions?

Tags: terminology

I'm the developer of a personal finance app for iOS called [My Finances](http://financesapp.net). The app supports repeating (daily, weekly, monthly and yearly) transactions and presents a summary of the repeating settings to the user e.g. *Every week on Sunday.*

I want to add quarterly and half-yearly repeating transactions and I'm not sure how to summarise them correctly. Would it be correct to summarise a quarterly repeating transactions starting on April 3rd like this: *Every quarter on 3rd day in 1st month*?

Same goes for half-yearly transactions.

**Update**: Rephrased question.

Comment: This question is not about an issue of personal finance that the OP is facing, but about a decision that the OP needs to make in his software development business. I vote to close.

Comment: I ask the question because maybe there is already a best-practice solution or an established term for this. I've rephrased the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quarterly events:**

You could say, *quarterly on the 3rd day of the quarter*, or *quarterly on the 3rd day of the 1st month of the quarter*. Either should be clear since there is agreement on how the year is divided into quarters. If you don't want to assume that your users will understand that the first quarter runs from January-March, you could use a phrasing like, *quarterly: next occurrence will be June 1st, 2014*. This phrasing allows for user confusion about how quarters generally work, but avoids the wordiness of listing all four annual instances.

You're still assuming that the user will understand that quarterly implies three-month intervals, but that's probably a low enough bar - one hopes. You still might want to explain it in a glossary or F.A.Q.

**Semi-annual events:**

For semi-annual events, there is no general agreement on where to break up the year into halves. I would suggest something like *semi-annually on 15th of the 1st and 7th months*, or *semi-annually on the second Monday of March and September*. Although there's less wordiness involved with listing both dates for semi-annual events, if you choose to identify only the next upcoming date for quarterly events, you could do the same here. For example, *semi-annually: next occurrence will be June 1st, 2014*.

**Post-script:**

Personally, I like the format that identifies the frequency and names the next upcoming date. When doing personal budgeting, that format may save users from dangerous errors related to momentary lapses on the math involved.

Comment: I really like the `quarterly on the 3rd day of the 1st month of the quarter`. Could someone say `every quarter` instead of `quarterly`? Also as a nonnative English speaker, I'm not sure when to use `yearly` and when `annually`.

Comment: @brutella Yes, "every quarter" will work in place of "quarterly." The difference between yearly and annually is that yearly is an adjective, while annually is an adverb. So yearly events occur annually. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're talking about human rather than astronomical phenomena, why not "On April 3rd this year and quarterly/biannually thereafter"?

Comment: I think it's hard for the user to forecast future dates when specifying the exact first transaction date. For a quarterly transaction which starts on `April 3rd` the next would be `July 3rd` - this takes some time for the user to figure out.